# YUI compressor vs Granule

Tags: java, javascript, css, minify

What are the difference between YUI Compressor (Yahoo) and Granule (Google) in minifying css and js files in a struts 2 and spring web application?

Is there any major differences between these two tools? I'm researching for best minifying tools and in the middle of choosing one of these. Is there any suggestion?

What are the pros and cons about using these two tools?

Answer (score 1):

I have used YUI Compressor for several projects and it's always worked perfectly but its deprecated now http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2012/10/16/state-of-yui-compressor/